# Android Service shutting down when function works longer than (about) 15 seconds

Tags: android, android-service, long-polling

I have a service which works with LongPoll and when I receive my data everything is OK, but when I don't receive data, rather I receive empty result (long polling max time == 25 sec) my service sometimes turning off manually (and I don't see it in list of services).

**So, how to keep this service (..always..) running?**

Recursive function, which works with long polling and at first calls in service's `onCreate()` (structure):

```
//"u" is "new utils()".
public class myservice extends Service {
  public static boolean started=false;
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "created qweqwe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    longpoll();
    this.started=true;
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.started=false;
  }
  private String url = "http://example.com/lp.php";
  private void longpoll() {
    try {
      String resp = u.getData(url); //max time of working u.getData(lpurl) - 25s.
      if (resp.length()>0) doSmthWithData(resp); //It works fine
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    longpoll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how to keep this service (..always..) running?

Tactically, based on the "15 seconds" in your question title, my guess is that you are doing this long poll on the main application thread. You need to do it on a background thread.

Strategically, you cannot keep a service "always running". You can use `startForeground()` to reduce the odds of your service being automatically destroyed, but the user and the OS can still get rid of your process (along with its service) at any time for any reason. Many users do not like services that are "always running"  because of the resources they waste, and therefore will attack developers of such services with task killers and low ratings on the Play Store.

Comment: I have updated the code. It starts in the main activity if (!myservice.started). Isn't service a background thread?

Comment: @anony_root: "Isn't service a background thread?" -- no, it is not. Services are in the background from a UI standpoint. They are not in the background with respect to the main application thread. `onStartCommand()` and all the other lifecycle methods of a service are called on the main application thread -- the same main application thread that powers your UI. And, the same rules apply: every millisecond you tie up that thread freezes the UI, and if you take ridiculously long on that thread, you will be terminated.

Comment: last thing: can I create notifications from background thread?

Comment: @anony_root: Yes, you can raise a `Notification` from a background thread.